# What is the issue with inheritance in this code?

Tags: python

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.num1=0
        self.num2=0
    def set1(self,score1,score2):
        self.num1=score1
        self.num2=score2
    def show1(self):
        print("num1",self.num1,"num2",self.num2)

class b(a):
    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

    def set2(self):
        self.sum=self.num1+self.num2
    def show2(self):
        print("d=",self.sum)

class c(b):
    def __init__(self):
        super.__init__()
    def set3(self):
        self.multiplication=self.num1*self.num2
    def show3(self):
        print("f=",self.multiplication)

objects=c()
objects.set1(1000,100)
objects.show1()
objects.set2()
objects.show2()
objects.set3()
objects.show3()
```

I wrote this code to work on the meaning of inheritance, but I receive:

```
    objects=c()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\New folder\2.py", line 23, in __init__
    super.__init__()
TypeError: descriptor '__init__' of 'super' object needs an argument
```

num1 and num2 are two numbers and I want to calculate sum and multiplication of them via concept of inheritance in Python.
I do not know what is the problem with.What is the problem with this code?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote `super.__init__()` instead of `super().__init__()` in `__init__` of class `c`.

If you are using Python 2 you will need to call `super` in the following way:  
`super(ClassName, self).__init__()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call super, right now its just a reference.

```
class c(b):

    super().__init__()
```

The other thing is that if you wanted to make this inheritance more robust, you could pass through all args and kwargs to `__init__` like so:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This would make your classes more flexible, and open to multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's how you used the `super()` built-in [Here the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super)

In your case, super need two argument: the class and an instance of the class.

In your `b.__init__` the synthax will be:

```
super(b,self).__init__()
```

here the solution for your problem:

```
class b(a):
    def __init__(self):
        super(b, self).__init__()
    def set2(self):
        self.sum=self.num1+self.num2
    def show2(self):
        print("d=",self.sum)

class c(b):
    def __init__(self):
        super(c, self).__init__()
    def set3(self):
        self.multiplication=self.num1*self.num2
    def show3(self):
        print("f=",self.multiplication)
```